# Getting the width of SVG text with a title on Node

Tags: node.js, svg.js

I'm using svg.js and svgdom on Node to generate SVG files. Here's my code:

```js
// set up svg.js and svgdom
const { createSVGWindow } = require('svgdom');
const window = createSVGWindow();
const document = window.document;
const { SVG, registerWindow } = require('@svgdotjs/svg.js');
registerWindow(window, document);
const draw = SVG(document.element).size(100, 100);

// generate SVG text and title
var title = draw.element('title').words('noun');
var text = draw.text('text').add(title);
var width = text.length();
```

That last line throws `TypeError: cannot read property 'style' of null` in svgdom/main-require.cjs:3721:38.

This works when I do it in the browser; something about moving to Node and svgdom causes it to fail. Is there another way I can calculate the width of this text element, or a different way to attach the title to the text? (The title is being used to show additional information on hover.) Calling `text.width()` always returns 0.

I'm using svg.js 3.0.16 and svgdom 0.1.8. Should I open an issue on one of them? If so, which one?

Comment: what is `document.element`? Shouldnt it be `document.documentElement`?

Comment: Oops! Made a mistake setting up svgdom. Yes, that's correct. Fixing it doesn't seem to fix my problem, though.